Receiving random money
Say, a crazy billionaire picks someone randomly from the phone book and donates 1million dollars.
Is this gambling for the receiver, or for the donator, for both or for none of them?

I don't see how it is gambling for anyone. Rather it is one person giving a gift to another, and he is using random chance to decide the recipient since to him everyone is equally eligible and he wishes to give everyone a fair chance of being chosen. Casting lots for a permissible reason is permissible: Quran 3:44, Quran 37:141, Bukhari 2686 - 2689.
On the other hand: Gambling is a transaction where multiple parties stake something of value, all of which goes to a winner (decided by luck or skill) and everyone else loses their staked property.
In your given example the party who gives the money is predetermined and fixed, the crazy billionaire will pay the entire amount and will never receive anything regardless of the outcome. The people in the phone-book also do not pay or risk anything regardless of the outcome.
